# Using Derivative Function Definition to find the Derivative

Tags: calculus

I am trying to use the Derivative Function Definition to show that $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$, where $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}$. I tried 3 different times, but I think there are some algebra mistakes.

I was thinking if I can cancel out the $\Delta x$ from the denominator, I can then apply $\lim_{x\to 0}\Delta x$ and get my answer. But I only gotten $-\frac{1}{2}x$ so far. My question is, is my approach incorrect? Or there is algebra mistake I kept repeating?

PS: I learned about the power rule, and derivative rules last week. But I would really like to learn where is my mistake or error.

[image: My work]

Comment: Nice handwriting.

Comment: You changed a sum to a product in the third line from the bottom.

Comment: @induktio the first thing I thought when I was reading this was "man, I sure wish my work was that neat!"

Comment: I wish I could draw lines that straight. Damn.

Comment: @DanZimm Right? I just wish more people knew the beauty and power of LaTeX...my handwriting is decent, but TeX...nothing can compare with the great Knuth!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very good up to near the end. Your addition suddenly turned into multiplication. You should instead have:
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \cdots \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{-\Delta x}{(\Delta x)(\sqrt{x + \Delta x})(\sqrt x) \cdot [\sqrt x + \sqrt{x + \Delta x}]} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{-1}{(\sqrt{x + \Delta x})(\sqrt x) \cdot [\sqrt x + \sqrt{x + \Delta x}]} \\
&= \frac{-1}{(\sqrt{x})(\sqrt x) \cdot [\sqrt x + \sqrt{x}]} \\
&= \frac{-1}{x \cdot [2\sqrt x]} \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}x^{-3/2}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Adrinao I see where my error is now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The error you made was when you passed from :

$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\dfrac{(\Delta x)(-1)}{(\Delta x)\left(\sqrt{x+\Delta x}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\left[\sqrt{x}\color{#C00}{\boldsymbol+}\left(\sqrt{x+\Delta x}\right)\right]},
$$

to

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}(-1)\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x+\Delta x}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\left[\sqrt{x}\color{#C00}{\small\bullet}\left(\sqrt{x+\Delta x}\right)\right]}.$$